# C# : How to Upload File to a Specific Folder using Google Drive API v3 - Windows Console Application

Tags: c#, file-upload, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to upload an image to my google drive using c#. This code works fine if i want to upload to root directory.
But i want to upload my images to specific folder in my Drive.
Suggestion Needed.

```
private static void UploadBasicImage(string file_path,DriveService service)
    {
        var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
        fileMetadata.Name = Path.GetFileName(path);
        fileMetadata.MimeType = "image/png";
        FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
        using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path,System.IO.FileMode.Open))
        {
            request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, fileMetadata.MimeType);
            request.Fields = "id";
            request.Upload();
        }
        var file = request.ResponseBody;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Solution I just Figured Out:

[Full Details are Here](https://qawithexperts.com/article/asp-net/upload-file-to-google-drive-using-google-drive-api-in-aspnet/236)

```
        public static void FileUploadInFolder(string folderId, string path, DriveService service)
    {
        var FileMetaData = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
        {
            Name = Path.GetFileName(path),
            MimeType = GetMimeType(path),
            //id of parent folder 
            Parents = new List<string>
                {
                    folderId
                }
        };
        FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
        //create stream and upload
        using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
        {
            request = service.Files.Create(FileMetaData, stream, FileMetaData.MimeType);
            request.Fields = "id";
            request.Upload();
        }
        var file1 = request.ResponseBody;
    }
```

Comment: can't seem to find GetMimeType ()